# Magento change hosting

Tags: magento

Hi I change my hosting I exported database, set database configuration but when I load my website it redirection me on my old website. Where is a problem? Where can I fint other settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change Settings in System - Configuration - Web - Unsecure/Secure - Base Url
Or update lines in database: table core_config data for path web/unsecure/base_url and web/secure/base_url to reflect your new domain name.

Comment: ...or just open phpmyadmin, open your db and search for your old url (fqdn version with http://www.). Edit the two entries that pop up in core_config_data and edit accordingly, remembering the final slash on the end.

Comment: If you moved recently, sometimes it takes some time to DNS servers resolve you to the other host IP. A workaround is: on the new host, use the temporary url they offer you, and redirect the old site to the new temporary url for one or two days. And after that, you can change your home_address as @PavelNovitsky said.